# Adding Layer package to Web Map in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, layer-package, arcgis-online-webmap

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1, and created a layer package of a raster file, but it does not allow me to add it to a web map in ArcGIS . It shows up in "My Content", but only allows me to download it or view it in ArcMap.

[image]

It is 6MB in size.

If there is some kind of size limit, how can I load this into a web map?

It is reclassified data from the Hansen Forest cover loss dataset. I also published a web service of the map, but it still doesn't display the raster data.

Answer (score 1):

Layer packages are not supported for display in map viewer. If you are displaying it in Desktop/Pro can you publish that from Share Layer - Share Web Map from those applications to Online as a hosted feature layer.

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/supported-items.htm